# (a) Does $f$ have a derivative? $ n^{th} $ derivative ? (b) Does $ f \ $ have an integral from $0$ to $1$?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the functions

1. $f(x)=x$  if $x$  is  rational  and  $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ if $x$  is  irrational
2. $f(x)=1$ if $x$  is  rational  and $f(x)=0$ if $x$  is  irrational.

Then check:

(a) Does $f$ have derivative? $n^{th}$ derivative?

(b) Does $f$ have an integral from $0$ to $1$?

(c) Does $f$ have a Taylor series expansion?

(d) Can we approximate $f$ by first degree polynomial?

**Answer:**

Since both the functions has no continuous derivative, they are not analytic functions. They do not have $n$th derivatives. They are not continuous and hence cannot be approximated by first degree polynomial. Since the functions are not analytic, they do not have Taylor series expansion.

**Am I right? Any help?**

Comment: It looks like what you've said is right so far. (b) is a subtle point, however, and it depends on whether the integral to which you're referring is the Riemann integral or the Lebesgue integral. Actually, for (d) there's something to be said for clarifying what you mean by "approximate"... Of course you can approximate something by a first degree polynomial, it's just that it might be a terrible approximation, depending on how you define a good approximation.

Comment: yep, approximation depends of the norm chosen, so since these functions are not continuous, it won't be possible to find good linear approximations for uniform convergence norm, but for integral norms (i.e. $L^p$) the rationals are negligible so for 2) the null function is a good approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Q 1, $f(x)$ is continuous only at $x=1$, and is nowhere differentiable, and therefore has no higher-order derivatives. For non-diffeentiability at $x=1,$ observe that if $y\to 1$ thru rational values then $(f(y)-f(1))/(y-1)\to 1$ but if $y\to 1$ thru irrational value then $(f(y)-f(1))/(y-1)\to -1.$

If $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-A)^n$ for all $x\in (-B+A,B+A)$ for some $B>0$ then $a_1=f'(A).$ In this Q, $f'$ does not exist.